# Windows command prompt blink cursor

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there a way to stop the cursor blinking in the Windows command prompt? I have tried setting blink speed to 'none' in Control Panel, but the bloody thing is still blinking me to insanity.

EDIT I didn't set the blink speed to 'none' properly. I did now and it works. I'll keep the question here anyway for future reference. /EDIT

Comment: you are refering to this problem: http://serverfault.com/questions/49074/non-blinking-block-cursor-in-windows-xp-command-prompt and these settings http://www.microsoft.com/enable/training/windowsxp/blinkrate.aspx ?

Comment: done deal 54321

Comment: They didn't used to have any way to do this and it has been bothering me for 20 years. Thanks for leaving this question up! I'm finally free!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Options, options.

1. http://www.microsoft.com/enable/training/windowsxp/blinkrate.aspx
2. Noblink: http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/noblink.html, TSR which allow no blinking cursors
3. Console: http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/, a better cmd.exe

Comment: Console is *not* a better `cmd.exe`. In fact, it has absolutely *nothing* to do with `cmd`. It's just a host for console processes. It doesn't care what process that is. Your second option will only work for command.com, I presume (can't test, since I'm on 64 bit)

Answer (score 6):

All you need can be done as simply as issuing:

```
control main.cpl keyboard
```

from `Run` prompt (<kbd>Win+R</kbd>) and setting the:

**Cursor blink rate** to **None** either by mouse or by keyboard shortcuts of:

<kbd>Alt+B</kbd> and <kbd>Left</kbd> button.

---

### Note

`control` keyword can be omitted.

---

`control` is actually the "short form" of:

```
c:\Windows\System32\control.exe
```

executable file which starts `.cpl` Control Panel files,

`main.cpl` being the argument file also residing in that directory.

:)

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command in Cmd and restart Cmd:

```
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v CursorBlinkRate /t REG_SZ /d -1 /f
```

This will set the the value of Registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop` value `CursorBlinkRate` to `-1`. Which will stop Command Prompt cursor blinking.